# python dictionary with list of tuples to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

How can a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    'RCLS1': [(0, 20),  (10, 112),  (20, 130), (30, 102)],
    'RCLS2': [(0, 16),(10, 53),(20, 96), (30, 45)]
}
```

be converted to a CSV with structure:

```
RCLS1,  0,  20
RCLS1, 10, 112
.
.
.
RLCS2, 30,  45
```

I have tried this:

```
with open(r'E:\data.csv', "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows((k,) + v for k, v in dct.items())
```

but this resulted in the following error:

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Comment: What are you hoping for the output to look like. Currently `v` is a list of tuples so `(k,) + v` is trying to add a `tuple` to a list of tuples which it can't do.

Comment: @AChampion agreed. Could you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Agree, my explanation of expected output was poorly written. Have included an example now.

Answer (score 2):

If what i understood from your question is correct, your are trying to do something like this (without the need to use of `csv` module):

```
a = {'RCLS1':[(0, 20),  (10, 112),  (20, 130), (30, 102)], 'RCLS2': [(0, 16),(10, 53),(20, 96), (30, 45)]}

with open('E:\data.csv', 'a+') as f:
    for k,v in a.items():
        f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(k,", ".join(", ".join(str(j) for j in k) for k in v)))
```

Output (The date in your file will be similar to this output):

```
RCLS1: 0, 20, 10, 112, 20, 130, 30, 102
RCLS2: 0, 16, 10, 53, 20, 96, 30, 45
```

Otherwise, if you want to have the data by pair you can do something like this:

```
with open('E:\data.csv', 'a+') as f:
    for k,v in a.items():
        f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(k, "".join(", ".join(str(k) for k in v))))
```

Output:

```
RCLS1: (0, 20), (10, 112), (20, 130), (30, 102)
RCLS2: (0, 16), (10, 53), (20, 96), (30, 45)
```

**Edit:**

A quick solution to your new update. You can do something like this:

```
a = {'RCLS1':[(0, 20),  (10, 112),  (20, 130), (30, 102)], 'RCLS2': [(0, 16),(10, 53),(20, 96), (30, 45)]}

with open('E:\data.csv', 'a+') as f:
    for k,v in a.items():
        for j in v:
            f.write("{0}: {1}\n".format(k, ", ".join(str(k) for k in j)))
```

Output:

```
RCLS2: 0, 16
RCLS2: 10, 53
RCLS2: 20, 96
RCLS2: 30, 45
RCLS1: 0, 20
RCLS1: 10, 112
RCLS1: 20, 130
RCLS1: 30, 102
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas. Looking at my original description, I understand your suggestion. Would you mind looking at the example of output format I have provided (after editing question)? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, @ChihebNexus, the last approach you suggested matches the output I am aiming for. Appreciate all of your suggestions. Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample input/output you provided, you can iterate through the dictionary's key-value pairs, then iterate through the list of tuple values associated with each key, build the associated CSV row string, and write it to the CSV file, like so:

```
dct = {'RCLS1':[(0, 20),  (10, 112),  (20, 130), (30, 102)], 'RCLS2': [(0, 16),(10, 53),(20, 96), (30, 45)]}
int_to_str = lambda int_value: str(int_value)

with open(r"data.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    for key, values in dct.items():
         for tuple_value in values:
             csv_row = [key] + list(map(int_to_str, list(tuple_value)))
             csv_file.write(", ".join(csv_row) + "\n")
```

**data.csv** results:

```
RCLS2, 0, 16
RCLS2, 10, 53
RCLS2, 20, 96
RCLS2, 30, 45
RCLS1, 0, 20
RCLS1, 10, 112
RCLS1, 20, 130
RCLS1, 30, 102
```

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I've edited the question to clarify the output. I was not clear enough before. My apologies. If you can please take another peek and share your thoughts. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JacamoFinane you're welcome. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: this looks great,  @Robert Valencia, thank you for showing me an effective of ways to arriving at the desired output. Appreciate your guidance. I've learned something new.

Comment: You're welcome @JacamoFinane! Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped/solved your problem.

Comment: Dear @Robert Valencia, I'm playing around with the various solutions and trying your suggestion results in "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list" for the line "csv_row = [key] + map(int_to_str, list(tuple_value))".  Do you have any suggestions to resolve?

Comment: @JacamoFinane that error occurs in Python 3 because map returns an iterable, so the returned value should be explicitly converted to a list. Please see the updated answer and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

one alternative answer using `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d={'RCLS1':[(0, 20),  (10, 112),  (20, 130), (30, 102)], 'RCLS2': [(0, 16),(10, 53),(20, 96), (30, 45)]}
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(d)


       RCLS1     RCLS2
0    (0, 20)   (0, 16)
1  (10, 112)  (10, 53)
2  (20, 130)  (20, 96)
3  (30, 102)  (30, 45)
[4 rows x 2 columns]

>>> dfs=df.stack().reset_index(level=0)

       level_0          0
RCLS1        0    (0, 20)
RCLS2        0    (0, 16)
RCLS1        1  (10, 112)
RCLS2        1   (10, 53)
RCLS1        2  (20, 130)
RCLS2        2   (20, 96)
RCLS1        3  (30, 102)
RCLS2        3   (30, 45)


>>> dfs=dfs[0].apply(pd.Series)  # break the tuples in column with "name"=0

        0    1
RCLS1   0   20
RCLS2   0   16
RCLS1  10  112
RCLS2  10   53
RCLS1  20  130
RCLS2  20   96
RCLS1  30  102
RCLS2  30   45


>>> dfs.to_csv('fileName.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you, @ab-user216125, this is perfect, too, b/c I am hoping to become more proficient in several ways of skinning the same cat. This will be added to the arsenal! Thank you

Comment: I am playing with the various solutions, @ab-user216125. My dictionary of thousands of items unfortunately to contain some values that are not the same length as others so when calling df=pd.DataFrame(d), the error, "arrays must all be same length" results. I am curious whether the pandas DF is still an option in this scenario?

Comment: if your RCLS1 and RCLS2 or RCLSn is changing in length you may end up with sparse DataFrames. In that case you need to consider if your data is what you think it is. Pandas can deal very well with missing data or by dropping rows/columns or by filling the missing values. Which way you will deal with those things is totally up to you.
If you like the answer, vote-up - everybody likes to earn points ;)